# Событие закрытия поисковой строки SearchRecentSuggestions

Tags: java, android

При реализации в приложении поиска с помощью SearchRecentSuggestions, при нажатии на кнопку поиска виджета, открывается виджет в котором есть строка ввода поискового запроса с крестиком для ее закрытия.
Как отловить событие нажатия на этот крестик?

Код абсолютно стандартный:
В onCreate:

```
SearchRecentSuggestions suggestions = new SearchRecentSuggestions(this,                       SearchSuggestionProvider.AUTHORITY, SearchSuggestionProvider.MODE);
suggestions.saveRecentQuery(query, null);
```

Далее:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Заполнение меню; элементы действий добавляются на панель приложения
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    search = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
    // К поиску из верхней панели:
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(true);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

searchable.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:hint="@string/fldSearchString"
    android:voiceSearchMode="showVoiceSearchButton|launchRecognizer"
    android:searchSuggestAuthority="com.example.SearchSuggestionProvider"
    android:searchSuggestSelection=" ?" >
</searchable>
```

Comment: для начала можно добавить сюда код создания данного виджета

Comment: добавил код в описание